# Reselect - Props undefined in selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I have one container with its selectors and It renders another container that has its other selectors.

The problem with that is that the second one, props are undefined and it breaks everything.

Here's the code (where props are undefined in the second selector):

***selectProductsState** props returning undefined.*

**One selector:**

```
const selectProductsState = () => ({ products }, props) => { return { products, props } };

const getCurrentProductFromParams = () => createSelector(
  selectProductsState(),
  getProductsItems(),
  ({ props }, items) => {
    const id = extractId(props.params);

    return items[id];
  }
);
```

**ProductContainer:**

```
class ProductPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (<OtherContainer />)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  hasLoadingErrors: getHasLoadingErrors(),
  productNotFound: getProductNotFound(),
  product: getProduct(),
  getCurrentProductFromParams
});
```

Another container has his own selectors.

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `params` prop passed from `react-router` to the `ProductPage` container.

So `params` it's not passed down to the `OtherContainer` automatically, therefore, params it's `undefined`

The solution is passing manually the prop to `OtherContainer`:

```
class ProductPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<OtherContainer params={this.props.params} />)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  hasLoadingErrors: getHasLoadingErrors(),
  productNotFound: getProductNotFound(),
  product: getProduct(),
  getCurrentProductFromParams
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably breaks because you try to extract a `props` property from an `undefined` object in your result function params (`{ props }`).

If receiving undefined from `selectProductsState` is an acceptable use case, you should simply rewrite the result function in order to take the edge case into account. Eg:

```
(productsState, items) => {
    if(productsState === undefined){
        return undefined;
    }
    const id = extractId(productsState.props.params);
    return items[id];
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not what I want. Props must never be undefined. The problem is that when I try to access props from a container that has a parent container with is selectors, props are undefined. Do you know what I mean? thanks